# Why no borders show up?

Tags: excel, vba, border

```
Dim rng2 As Range:
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D:E", ActiveSheet.Cells.End(xlUp))
 
 With rng2
 .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
 .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinous
   
 End With
```

I understand my code like this.

- rng2 is assigned to the Range "D:E" on the ActiveSheet. All Cells count to rng2 as long no blank cell occurs (End(xlUp))
- With rng2 i assign to my Range rng2 the above mentioned settings which are left arrangement which works and Borders which shall in a continously Syle frame my rng2 - this does not work

I have to say that the first cell of D:E includes a value in D1 (header) but not in E1 (no header) is this the problem?

**EDIT 17.05.21 full code**

```
Sub Duplicate()

Dim nA As Long, nD As Long, i As Long, rc As Long
Dim s As String, j As Long

    Range("A:A").Copy Range("D1")
    Range("B1").Copy Range("E1")
    Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    rc = Rows.Count
    nA = Cells(rc, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    nD = Cells(rc, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    
       For i = 2 To nD
        v = Cells(i, 4)
        V2 = ""
        For j = 2 To nA
         If v = Cells(j, 1) Then
            V2 = V2 & Cells(j, 2) & ","
        End If
            
        Next j
        Cells(i, 5) = Mid(V2, 1)
    Next i

'neu
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D1", "E" & lastrow)
 
 With rng2
 .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
 .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   
 End With

Debug.Print

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach should be like this:

```
Dim rng2 As Range
dim lastrow as long

lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D1", "E" & lastrow)
 
 With rng2
 .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
 .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   
 End With
```

In additional, there is a typo on your code,

```
xlContinous should be xlContinuous
```

Continue to sort your row for the border issue. Assuming you have 2 col with difference row value. Col F has 8 rows, while Col H has 5 rows:

[image]

In order to obtain lastrow for different row, you can use the code as following:

```
Sub t()

Dim lastrowCola As Long
Dim lastrowColb As Long

lastrowCola = Sheet1.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Row
Debug.Print lastrowCola

lastrowColb = Sheet1.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row
Debug.Print lastrowColb

End Sub
```

So debug.print for lastrowCola is 8, while lastrowColb is 5. Based on your scenario, you can adjust accordingly.

Comment: Wow good spoted! • Use `Option Explicit` that saves your day! I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Ya, it is default setting since I learn VBA first day, recommend for everyone to do so.

Comment: @kin Siang thanks :) i just copied your code, i get borders but i get these far beyond the rng2 ...i have a UsedRange till Row 6 and Borders till Row 34 ..makes any sense? ..my declaration was indeed off ...didnt think about it because its another laptop

Comment: It is unlikely to happen if your usedrange.row is 6 but the border until row 34. You can used step into to check the value of the variable is correct. Or you may share what is your sample data in picture , so that I can have better idea for the outcome.

Comment: Try used debug.print to see the value of the usedrange, maybe you have blank row that is used

Comment: @Kin Siang i figured out by using Debug.Print that the Border is dependent by the source data ...unfortuanetly my code was just a snippet to focus on the right spot. I added the whole code to my question.

Comment: You can check my edit answer, I think should be able to solve your problem after you copy and paste value.  After that, you can shape your cell based on different last row on different column.